# Convert .sqlite file to .db file for ROOM pre-populate database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I started working in the Android ROOM persistence library and came across [Pre-Populating database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate). In this article, they have mentioned adding .db file to the assets folder. But the issue is how to convert .sqlite file into .db file online.

This is totally a new project where there are only read operations with all the data pre-loaded. I am trying to consume it using the Room library but am failing to do so.

Please help me in getting the best way to either convert .sqlite file to .db file or any other way programmatically doing it so.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question but sqlite doesn't care what the extension is, as long as it is in the right format. So you can just change the extension of the file, no? That is, if you have a sqlite database with extension .sqlite, just change it to extension .db

Comment: @topsail I did that and it worked. But now I started getting an error.

``(26) file is not a database in "PRAGMA journal_mode"
SQLiteDatabase        
E  Database corruption detected in open()
                                                                                                    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is not a database (code 26 SQLITE_NOTADB): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode``

Comment: Where did you get this file from?  Are you sure its the correct format for the version of sqlite you're using, and that it isn't encrypted?

Comment: Where did "PRAGMA journal_mode" come from?  The first line of the .sqlie file, somewhere else?

Comment: @GabeSechan I created this file from the XAMPP server localhost in SQL format and then convert this file online into .sqlite.

Comment: SQL isn't a format.  It's a language.  If this file is just a series of SQL statements then it's not a db of any type, its a file that needs to be executed line by line by the db to create a database.  And whether that will work depends on the flavor of SQL understood by whatever you used to generate this and SQLite

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is create an SQLite database based upon the XAMPP database using XAMPP to export the XAMPP database and an SQLite Tool (Navicat, DBeaver, DB Browser for SQlite, SQlite Studio), the resultant file can then be copied into the assets folder.

**However** Room is very strict in it's schema expectations and DOES NOT support the flexibility of SQLite's column types. As such it is suggested that first you define the `@Entity` annotated classes (the tables and indexes) then provide an `@Database` annotated class where the entities parameter of the `@Database` annotation specifies the `@Entity` annotated classes. At this stage compiling the project will generate the SQL for the tables and indexes and thus will be the tables that Room expects.

---

Perhaps consider this example, the XAMPP database (example):-

[image]

The first stage is to create the `@Entity` annotated classes (Java has been used as you have not specified the language). So in the project in Android Studio:-

Class **Contact** :-

```
@Entity
class Contact {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long contact_id=null;  /* XAAMPP INT no need for AUTOINCREMENT i.e. autoGenerate= true in the @PrimaryKey annotation */
    String contact_type; /* XAMPP VARCHAR */
    String contact_detail; /* XAMPP TEXT */
    String contact_notes;
}
```

- so VARCHAR and TEXT equate to a String member/field
- any integer type can be int, Integer, long, Long, byte, Byte all of which end up being SQLite type INTEGER when processed by Room.

  - AUTOINCREMENT for SQLite is inefficient and not needed see https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html
  - Long .... = null; has been used as long being a primitive has a default value of 0. No value (null) for INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (an alias of the rowid) results in value being automatically generated and hence effectively AUTOINCREMENT.
- Room will only generate column types INTEGER (integer types), REAL (floating point types), TEXT (String types) and BLOB (byte array/ stream types) any other type in the pre-populated database and an exception will result (expected .... found ....).

Class **Student** :-

```
@Entity
class Student {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long student_id=null;
    @NotNull
    String student_forename;
    @NotNull
    String student_surname;
    @NotNull
    String student_street_address;
    @NotNull
    String student_city;
    @NotNull
    String student_county;
    @NotNull
    String student_country;
    @NotNull
    String student_dob;
    @NotNull
    String student_email;

    Student(){}
    @Ignore
    Student(long id,String student_forename, String student_surname,String student_street_address, String student_city, String student_county, String student_country, String student_dob, String student_email) {
        this.student_forename = student_forename;
        this.student_surname = student_surname;
        this.student_street_address = student_street_address;
        this.student_city = student_city;
        this.student_county = student_county;
        this.student_country = student_country;
        this.student_dob = student_dob;
        this.student_email = student_email;
    }
    @Ignore
    Student(String student_forename, String student_surname, String student_street_address, String student_city, String student_county, String student_country, String student_dob, String student_email) {
        this.student_forename = student_forename;
        this.student_surname = student_surname;
        this.student_street_address = student_street_address;
        this.student_city = student_city;
        this.student_county = student_county;
        this.student_country = student_country;
        this.student_dob = student_dob;
        this.student_email = student_email;
    }
}
```

Class **StudentContactMap** (Foreign Key added for referential integrity):-

```
@Entity(
        tableName = "student_contact_map" /* name of the table different to class - not really needed - example of how to */
        , primaryKeys = {"student_map","contact_map"} /* composite primary key  as can't have multiple @PrimaryKey annotations */
        /* Optional Foreign Keys to enforce referential integrity */
        , foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Student.class,
                        parentColumns = {"student_id"},
                        childColumns = {"student_map"},
                        /* Optional but simplifies referential integrity maintenance */
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                ),
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Contact.class,
                        parentColumns = {"contact_id"},
                        childColumns = {"contact_map"},
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                )
        }
)
class StudentContactMap {
    long student_map;
    /* Added index as Room will warn about full table scan potential */
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    long contact_map;
}
```

An `@Dao` annotated interface (could be an abstract class) not required at this stage **AllDAOs** (can have multiple but for convenience just one):-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    Long insert(Contact contact);
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    Long insert(Student student);
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    Long insert(StudentContactMap studentContactMap);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM student")
    List<Student> getAllStudents();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM contact")
    List<Contact> getAllContacts();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM student_contact_map")
    List<StudentContactMap> getAllStudentContactMaps();

}
```

An `@Database` annotated class including singleton approach to getting the database instance, **TheDatabase** (obviously could be named otherwise):-

```
@Database(entities = {Contact.class,Student.class,StudentContactMap.class}, exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    /* method to retrieve the databases @Dao annotated interface (can have multiple such interfaces/abstract classes) */
    abstract AllDAOs getAllDAOs();

    /* For singleton approach */
    private static volatile TheDatabase INSTANCE;
    static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE==null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for convenince of demo */
                    .createFromAsset("the_database.db") /* asset name can be different to database name */
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

**Compile to generate expected schema (SQL)**

Ctrl + F9 will compile the project. From **Android View** java(generated) will contain a class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with **_Impl*.

Within that class there is a method **createAllTables** with SQL for each component (table index) that Room itself would create. i.e. the EXACT schema that Room expects to find.

[image]

Now you can move to create the pre-populated database in the SQLite tool (Navicat used).

For each component (table/index except the room_master_table) copy the SQL from the generated java to an empty connection/database and the window/view that allows you to run SQL (you can run the SQL) e.g. :-

[image]

**Loading the data**

Switch to XAMPP and export the database as SQL e.g. in Notepad or whatever you get something along the lines of :-

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `example`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `contact`
--

CREATE TABLE `contact` (
  `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contact_type` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `contact_detail` text NOT NULL,
  `contact_notes` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `contact`
--

INSERT INTO `contact` (`contact_id`, `contact_type`, `contact_detail`, `contact_notes`) VALUES
(1, 'Mobile', '0000 000 000', ''),
(3, 'Mobile', '1111 111 111', ''),
(4, 'Mobile', '2222 222 222', '');
....
```

As the tables have been created according to Room's expectations all that is required is to populate them using the insert statements so editing the export SQL:-

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `contact`
--

INSERT INTO `contact` (`contact_id`, `contact_type`, `contact_detail`, `contact_notes`) VALUES
(1, 'Mobile', '0000 000 000', ''),
(3, 'Mobile', '1111 111 111', ''),
(4, 'Mobile', '2222 222 222', '');

--
-- Dumping data for table `student`
--

INSERT INTO `student` (`student_id`, `student_forename`, `student_surname`, `student_street_address`, `student_city`, `student_county`, `student_country`, `student_dob`, `student_email`) VALUES
(1, 'Fred', 'Blogs', '1 Somewhere Place', 'London', 'Middlesex', 'England', '2002-03-21', 'fblogs@student_mail.org'),
(2, 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Nowhere House', 'Henley on Thames', 'Berkshire', 'England', '2001-08-11', 'jdoe@student_mail.org');

--
-- Dumping data for table `student_contact_map`
--

INSERT INTO `student_contact_map` (`student_map`, `contact_map`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 3);
```

Just in case instead of just `INSERT INTO` the inserts are changed to `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO`.

Running the SQL results in :-

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `contact` (`contact_id`, `contact_type`, `contact_detail`, `contact_notes`) VALUES
(1, 'Mobile', '0000 000 000', ''),
(2, 'Mobile', '1111 111 111', ''),
(3, 'Mobile', '2222 222 222', '')
> Affected rows: 3
> Time: 0.024s


--
-- Dumping data for table `student`
--

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `student` (`student_id`, `student_forename`, `student_surname`, `student_street_address`, `student_city`, `student_county`, `student_country`, `student_dob`, `student_email`) VALUES
(1, 'Fred', 'Blogs', '1 Somewhere Place', 'London', 'Middlesex', 'England', '2002-03-21', 'fblogs@student_mail.org'),
(2, 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Nowhere House', 'Henley on Thames', 'Berkshire', 'England', '2001-08-11', 'jdoe@student_mail.org')
> Affected rows: 2
> Time: 0.024s


--
-- Dumping data for table `student_contact_map`
--

INSERT OR IGNORE  INTO `student_contact_map` (`student_map`, `contact_map`) VALUES
(1, 1)
,(1, 2)
,(2, 3)
> Affected rows: 3
> Time: 0.024s
```

i.e. All data has been successfully inserted as expected.

Save the database, check that only the one file exists that there are no files the same names as the database suffixed with -wal or -shm (-journal file can be ignored).

- -wal/-shm file are files used when the database is using Write Ahead Logging. The -wal file contains part of the database. Closing the database should write the -wal to the database and empty and delete the -wal file (with Navicat you have to exit Navicat).

So the end result is a file aka the database e.g. :-

[image]

This file can then be copied and pasted into the assets folder e.g.:-

[image]

- note the file was renamed accordingly

**Time to test**

To test the copy of the pre-populated database an instance of the @Database annotated class must be obtained and also an attempt must be made to access the database (it is not until an attempt is made to access the database that it will be opened, getting an instance does not open the database). As such some activity code will be needed e.g. :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase dbInstance;
    AllDAOs dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbInstance = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = dbInstance.getAllDAOs();

        for (Student s: dao.getAllStudents()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Student is " + s.student_forename + " " + s.student_surname + " etc");
        }
    }
}
```

When run then the log includes:-

```
D/DBINFO: Student is Fred Blogs etc
D/DBINFO: Student is Jane Doe etc
```

**Success**